# Why seaborn are using different colors in google colab and my local jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I don't think that probelm in version,

google colab

python --version = Python 3.7.14
sns.**version** = 0.11.2

local

python --version = Python 3.8.13
sns.**version** = 0.12.0

```py
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(9,5)})
sns.stripplot(data = train_df, x= "Class", y = "Easting");
```

and colors differents
[image: local]

[image: colab]

How to do colors on my local (all blue) the same as on colab?

Comment: Did you check the [`stripplot` docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html)?

Comment: Yes and I still don't understand why the same code gives different results

Comment: Thx!:D I found
"If the hue variable is numeric, it will be mapped with a quantitative palette by default (note that this was not the case prior to version 0.12):"

Answer (score 0):

"If the hue variable is numeric, it will be mapped with a quantitative palette by default (note that this was not the case prior to version 0.12):"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).